# RestController PutMapping malformed url when using "[]"

Tags: spring-boot, rest, http

I have a Spring App witch use a controller like this:

```
@PutMapping("/block/{blockid}/service/{serviceid}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> config(@PathVariable blockid, @PathVariable serviceid, @RequestBody String body) {
{
```

And I using Postman to test the request, if i send this request to this url:
url: **localhost:7000/block/myBlockTest/service/externalServiceTest[0]**

Response this error:

> **Description** The server cannot or will not process the
>   request due to something that is perceived to be a        client error
>   (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or
>   deceptive request routing).

I know the problem is **"[0]"** in the url.

Is there any way I can send this in the URL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just need modify the request to be localhost:7000/block/myBlockTest/service/externalServiceTest%5B0%5D

Special parameters. 
https://cachefly.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215068626-How-to-format-URLs-that-have-special-characters-in-the-filename-